# SQL Show most common

Tags: sql, ms-access

First of all, apologies for my english.
For school, I have to make a SQL.
The instructions are pretty easy,
I have to show the most common "MERK" and the amount of times it's used.

For example

I have 500 Cars, 200 Lamborghinis.

Then I have to make sure it only shows something like this:

```
LAMBORGHINI - 200
```

That's the only thing, but I totally forgot how to do that.

Some extra information:

```
Column = MERK_code
FROM = Auto
```

If something is not clear enough, please ask me. I know my english is really bad but I tried to explain it as good as possible.

Comment: Important: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: `COUNT()`

Comment: Reminds me of my Engineering days. 
`SELECT MERK_code,COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE MERK_code='LAMBORGHINI ' GROUP BY MERK_code`. Give it a try. I can give the exact query, if you give me the completed table structure. Make sure you study this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I've tried different things like:
SELECT MERK_code, COUNT(MERK_code) AS Amount
FROM Auto
GROUP BY MERK_code
ORDER BY Amount DESC;

But when i do this, i get a pop-up which shows the text "Amount" but that's something i dont want.